# How to access a JSON key dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following:

```
var parsed_contacts = jQuery.parseJSON(conts);
$('#contacts > li > a').click(function(event){
          target_id = event.target.id; //yields a Google App Engine entity key bound to a <a> id property. (e.g "agdldHJlYnVncg0LEgdDb250YWN0GFgM", with quotes)
          console.log(parsed_contacts[target_id]); //Yields undefined
});
```

And here's what i get from `console.log(parsed_contacts)` :

[image]
[Click for bigger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHSM2.png)

How should i proceed? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output, it seems you need `parsed_contacts[0][target_id]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your string contains quotes, then may want to strip them out before passing it to `console.log`:

```
target_id = target_id.replace(/['"]/g,'');
```

Comment: Turns out it doesn't have the quotes, but the console showed it with quotes in one of the attempts...